# Connection reset jax-rs and wildfly10

Tags: java-8, jax-rs, wildfly-10

If I try to make a site call with jax-rs and wildfly10 I have connection problems but if I make the same call from curl from the server where wildfly10 is working it works perfectly.

This is the wildfly error:

2020-06-18 18:01:46,075 INFO [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] (default task-48) I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to {s}->https://xyx.it:443: Connection reset

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: xyz.it doesn't seem to host HTTPS, I can't get a connection in my Chrome either.

Comment: it is an example, xyx is an url from private company

Comment: Then, without seeing your code or knowing much: Firewall maybe? Can your java code access other sites (e.g. google)?

Comment: Firewall is impossible because I have access by curl in the same server. I can try with other sites, thanks for this suggestion